Unable to install GD library on docker container
I have a dockerfile as shown below:
# Use an official PHP 5.6 image as the base
FROM php:5.6-apache

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install PHP extensions, including GD
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && a2enmod rewrite

# Copy your application files into the container
COPY ./sites/site_old/php /usr/local/lib/php/

# Expose port 80 for Apache
EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache when the container starts
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

Everything works fine until I try to install gd-library. Then the mess begins: It seems container being in build process has problem to access Debian repos and libraries while building container. Here is the output:
> [3/3] RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev &&     docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg &&     docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && a2enmod rewrite:                                  
0.430 Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
0.434 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                              
0.438 Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
0.445 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0.448 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.454 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
0.456 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.460 Ign:8 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
0.462 Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
0.465 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.469 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
0.478 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.482 Ign:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release
0.485 Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
0.488 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.493 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
0.514 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.517 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.546 Ign:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
0.568 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.571 Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
0.587 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.592 Ign:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
0.616 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
0.632 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.642 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.671 Ign:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
0.692 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.715 Ign:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
0.738 Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
0.739 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.741 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.748 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
0.755 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.767 Ign:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
0.768 Ign:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
0.781 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
0.801 Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
0.801   404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.38.132 80]
0.801 Ign:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main all Packages
0.807 Ign:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
0.821 Err:12 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
0.821   404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
0.860 Err:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
0.860   404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.38.132 80]
0.871 Reading package lists...
0.888 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
0.888 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
0.888 W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
0.888 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.38.132 80]
0.888 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.38.132 80]
0.888 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
0.888 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
Dockerfile:8
--------------------
   7 |     # Install PHP extensions, including GD
   8 | >>> RUN apt-get update && \
   9 | >>>     apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev && \
  10 | >>>     docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg && \
  11 | >>>     docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && a2enmod rewrite
  12 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev &&     docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg &&     docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && a2enmod rewrite" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

Here is my docker-compose.yml:
  site_old:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./sites/site_old/Dockerfile
    container_name: site_old
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./sites/site_old/src:/var/www/html
    environment:
      DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'
    networks:
      - appnet
    depends_on:
      - site_old-db


Here is update:
when I am trying to install nano with the command
apt-get update && apt-get install nano -y
I get same:
...
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.38.132 80]
...


You’ll also need to update references to the security repository. But really, you should use a newer base image (and presumably migrate off of PHP 5.6, which I imagine is the main constraint).
